# Attribute for duration on <audio> tags

Tags: javascript, metadata, html5-audio, preload

When working with `<audio>` tags I usually set the `preload="metadata"` in order to reduce bandwidth. Still this triggers a request on page load because the browser retrieves the duration of the file.

Is there a way to set the duration to an `<audio>` tag via an attribute? That way no request at all would be needed for the browser to display the duration prior to starting it. Something like:

```
<audio src="myfile.mp3" duration="600" preload="none">
```

Whereby 600 would be seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by setting `audio.src` with bytes for an "empty" audio file. For example, an RIFF/WAV file could be created for your required duration, and the browser renders the duration time in the UI.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('audio[data-duration]').forEach(initAudio)

function initAudio(audio) {
  // 0s 8-bit Mono Linear PCM 8000Hz WAV header
  const sampleRate = 8000
  const wavHeader = new Uint32Array([1179011410, 36, 1163280727, 544501094, 16, 65537, sampleRate, sampleRate, 524289, 1635017060, 0])

  const { duration, url } = audio.dataset

  // PCM8 WAV data
  const wavData = new Uint8Array(Math.ceil(duration * sampleRate))
  const dataSize = wavData.byteLength

  // set sizes
  wavHeader.set([dataSize + 36], 1)
  wavHeader.set([dataSize], 10)

  audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([wavHeader, wavData]))

  // swap audio with url to play
  audio.addEventListener('play', () => {
    audio.src = url
    audio.play()
  }, { once: true })
}
```

```html
<audio controls
  data-duration="15.13"
  data-url="https://opus-bitrates.anthum.com/audio/music-96.opus" />
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but a) this overrides the src of the audio and thus the file won't be played anymore and b) there is no `loadedmetadata` event when setting `preload="none"`.

Comment: `src` can be swapped to the url when the user initiates playback. This allows the network request to be avoided until initiated on play. `preload="none"` is not needed here.